# The element always moves on resizing the browser

Tags: html, css

For example: all the elements on the div first always move on the top of the slider I have. I don't know how to stick them on the same place when resizing the browser.

```
<h1 style="font-family:Raleway;font-weight:bold;font-size:26px;text-transform:uppercase;color:#000000;color:rgb(0, 0, 0);margin-top:40px;text-align:center">ABOUT US</h1>
<div class="underline1" style="margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;top:620px;width:105px;height:2px;background-color:#FF8A00"></div>
<div class="underline2" style="margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;top:629px;width:51px;height:2px;background-color:#FF8A00;margin-top:5px"></div>

<div class="first">
    <img style="margin-top:60px;width:47%;height:47%;margin-left:100px;"src="img/image-section1.png"/>
    <h1 style="margin-top:-485px;margin-left:780px;font-family:Raleway;font-weight:bold;font-size:18px;text-transform:uppercase;color:#444444">Welcome to Ultramax</h1>
    <p style="margin-left:780px;width: 472px;height: 354px;font-family:Raleway;font-size:15px;color:#636363;line-height:35px">Lorem Ipsum
    Is Simply Dummy Text The Printing And Typesetting 
    Industry. Lorem Ipsum Has Been The Industry's Of The Printing And Typesetting Industry. 
    Lorem Ipsum Has Been The Industry's The Printing And Typesetting Industry. 
    Lorem Ipsum Has Been The Industry's Standard Dummy Text Ever Since The 1500s, 
    When An Unknown Printer Took A Galley Of Type And Scrambled It To Make A Type Specimen Book.
    It Has Survived Not Only Five Centuries, But Also The Leap Into Electronic Typesetting, 
    Remaining EssentiallyIt Has Survived Not Only Five CenturiesLorem 
    Ipsum Is Simply Dummy Text Of The Printing And Typesetting Industry.</p>
    <button id="button-section1">LEARN MORE</button>
</div>
```

Comment: can you elaborate what your problem is?

Comment: and the button of my slider i have that code i paste it in the post, everytime resize the browser the image resized and thats fine, but all in the <div first> it goes up on the slider, i want to reduce the <p> and <h1> from going on the slider and keep sticking on the same place.

Comment: when i copy-paste your code what I see is heading at top with text in right. Then comes the button in left and the write-up in somewhat middle.

Comment: well, i doesnt want it to be aligned to the bottom of the image, i want it to be beside the image.

Comment: Just last time, clarify me. There's a image at top middle. Then there's h1 in center middle and then in bottom row there's text in left and button at right?

Comment: here i screenshot for you http://imgh.us/Capture_552.jpg

Comment: every time i resize the web browser, the <h1> and <p> moves to the top.

Comment: i want the image and the h1 and p to stretch with me like here: http://preview.themeforest.net/item/ultimax-onepage-html-template/full_screen_preview/19661665?_ga=1.218637851.328877626.1486953441

Comment: did you find the solution ?

Comment: @SamMohamed It worked then? :D

Comment: yes it worked, but i still confused why do you add the second h1 instead of div?

Comment: @SamMohamed Still confused?

Comment: Nope, i got it, thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some ideas that I have used here.

1. The `About Us` and the lines area as follows
2. Now I used a `parent div` with `width 100%`
3. Then I used 2 `child div`s for the pic and the body
4. Note the width I have used = 50%, thus dividing the parent div in 2 columns
5. The value in `float` demonstrates where the `child div`s are aligned

This is what you can use..

```
<html>
<body>
<h1 style="font-family:Raleway;font-weight:bold;font-size:26px;text-transform:uppercase;color:#000000;color:rgb(0, 0, 0);text-align:center;margin-top:50px">ABOUT US</h1>
<div class="underline1" style="margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;top:620px;width:105px;height:2px;background-color:#FF8A00"></div>
<div class="underline2" style="margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;top:629px;width:51px;height:2px;background-color:#FF8A00;margin-top:5px"></div>
<br><br><br>
<div style ="width: 100%; margin:0 auto;">

    <div style="width: 50%; height: 50%; float:left">
        <h1 style="text-align:right;margin-right:50px"><img style=" width: 80%;height: auto%;" src = "test.jpg" </h1>
    </div>
    <div style="width: 50%; height: 50%; float:right; ">
            <h1 style="text-align:left;margin-left:50px;font-family:Raleway;font-weight:bold;font-size:18px;text-transform:uppercase;color:#111111">Welcome to Ultramax</h1>
            <p style="text-align:left;margin-left:50px;font-family:Raleway;font-size:15px;color:#636363;line-height:35px">Lorem Ipsum
            Is Simply Dummy Text The Printing And Typesetting 
            Industry. Lorem Ipsum Has Been The Industry's Of The Printing And Typesetting Industry. 
            Lorem Ipsum Has Been The Industry's The Printing And Typesetting Industry. 
            Lorem Ipsum Has Been The Industry's Standard Dummy Text Ever Since The 1500s, 
            When An Unknown Printer Took A Galley Of Type And Scrambled It To Make A Type Specimen Book.
            It Has Survived Not Only Five Centuries, But Also The Leap Into Electronic Typesetting, 
            Remaining EssentiallyIt Has Survived Not Only Five CenturiesLorem 
            Ipsum Is Simply Dummy Text Of The Printing And Typesetting Industry.</p>
            <button style="text-align:left;margin-left:50px;"id="button-section1">LEARN MORE</button>
    </div>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Here's a screenshot..
[image]

And on resizing it's like

[image]

You can download the image from the site you have provided.

Comment: @SamMohamed Ahh! that's a lame trick to make images appear in center. Actually I faced and do face a lot of problems making images appear in center, so just use it to fool the browser on thinking it as a header when it finally realizes it's an image. :p

Comment: Awesome work, sorry another question why you didnt close the div you used here...    <div style ="width: 100%; margin:0 auto;">

Comment: @SamMohamed That's a typo.. Corrected.. :)

Comment: You should explain what you are doing rather than just giving the solution. Just writing code for people defeats the purpose of stackoverflow.